# Django add common conditions in model

Tags: python, django

I have model

```
class QuerySetManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return self.model.QuerySet(self.model)

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = QuerySetManager()
    STATUS = (
         (1, 'PENDING'),
         (2, 'ACTIVE'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512,blank=False,null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=1,choices=STATUS)
    class QuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
        def active(self):
            return self.filter(status=2)
```

When I try to access this way

```
Post.objects.active().filter(other_condition='xxx').all()
```

it throws error `'QuerySetManager' object has no attribute 'active'`

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Because `QuerySetManager` doesn't have `active`. It can be called `Post.QuerySet().active()`. But main thing is. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't understand what you're doing here at all. The way to get a manager to return a queryset with the same methods is to use the [`as_manager` classmethod](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods).

```
class PostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(status=2)

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = PostQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Comment: I am wrong tried some other solution for some other problem but your understanding is correct thanks